# Material Tailwind Select Options

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css

I added a select element with Material Tailwind, and I separated one of my option elements for redirection to a different page. Below that, I mapped an array to generate additional options. However, when I select a product, they don't appear.However, when I comment out the option that redirects to another page at the top, the selected option below becomes visible.

```
 <Select
          label="Brand"
         name="brandId"
          value={data?.brandId?._id || data?.brandId}
          size="lg"
          onChange={(value)=>handleChange(value,"brandId")}
          // selected={(element) =>
          //   element &&
          //   React.cloneElement(element, {
          //     disabled: true,
          //   })
          // }
        >
          <Option onClick={() => navigate("/stock/brands/")}>
            Add New Brand
          </Option>
          {brands.map((item) => (
            <Option value={item._id} key={item._id}>
              {item.name}
            </Option>
          ))}
```

To resolve this issue, I added the 'selected' parameter inside the select element, as recommended in Material UI. However, the problem persists.

Comment: Does it even have anything to do with the redirect behavior - or do you get the same result, when you _don't_ put the `onClick` handler onto that first, separate option?

Comment: (Click handlers for option elements are a rather bad idea to begin with, the browser behavior can be inconsistent. Handling this within the change handler - redirecting from within there, if the selected option was the first one - would be the better alternative, IMHO.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is using individual-rendered and mapped components. Don't know how Material Tailwind is handling child element renders but clearly they don't handle this kind of scenerios.

Solution is adding onClick option to brands array. You can add your onClick option to beggining of brands array individually. Now it'll work. (See working example below)

```
const brands = [
  { value: "1", label: "Option 1", id: "100" },
  { value: "2", label: "Option 2", id: "200" },
  { value: "3", label: "Option 3", id: "300" },
]

const HomePage = () => {
  const navigate = useNavigate()
  const navigateOption = {
    id: "400",
    label: "Add Brand",
    value: "4",
    onClick: () => navigate("/add-brand"),
  }
  const myOptions: Brand[] = [navigateOption, ...brands]
  return (
    <Select label="Brand" name="brandId" placeholder={"Select"}>
      {myOptions.map((option) => (
        <Option key={option.id} value={option.id} onClick={option.onClick}>
          {option.label}
        </Option>
      ))}
    </Select>
  )
}
```

Comment: also you can see my local reproducion from [this repo](https://github.com/borabiricik/material-tailwindcss)

Comment: Thank you very much for your response. It solved my Option problem, but now it doesn't display the value entered in the label; it shows the first value in the array,I also need to fix that. Do you have any information about why the label inside the select is not visible?

Comment: Could you share an example code piece for that ? That'd be very helpful to reproduce in my local

Comment: const { firms } = useSelector((state) => state.stock);

const myFirm = [
  {
    _id: "",
    name: "Add New Firm",
    onClick: () => navigate("/stock/firms"),
  },
  ...firms,
];

  <Select
    label="Firm"
    name="firmId"
    value={data?.firmId?._id || data?.firmId}
    size="lg"
    onChange={(value) => handleChange(value, "firmId", "select")}
  >
    {myFirm?.map((item) => (
      <Option value={item._id} key={item._id} onClick={item.onClick}>
        {item.name}
      </Option>
    ))}
  </Select>